Building a DFA/NFA to prove that a language is regular - exercise
I was given the following exercise and am having a hard time coming up with an intuition for it.
Given a regular language $L$  on the alphabet $\Sigma$, prove that the following language is regular by building an automaton:
$$
L'= \{u\sigma v \mid u,v\in \Sigma^*, \sigma uv\in L\}
$$
My first thought was to of course use the DFA I get from L (because it is regular), and insert a loop with all letters at the first state $q_0$. But my instructor said there's a problem with that, which I didn't really understood.
Would be happy to hear any ideas, thanks.

I suppose that $\sigma$ is a letter of $\Sigma$. Let ${\cal A} = (Q, \Sigma, E, q_0, F)$ be a finite deterministic automaton accepting $L$: as usual, $Q$ is the set of states, $E$ is the set of transitions, $q_0$ is the initial state and $F$ is the set of final states.
Hint.
For each state $q$ and each subset $S$ of $Q$, let $L(q, S)$ be the regular language accepted by the automaton $(Q, \Sigma, E, q, S)$.
If $\sigma uv \in L$, there is a successful path, labelled by $u\sigma v$, from $q_0$ to some final state $f$:
$$
  q_0 \xrightarrow{u} p \xrightarrow{\sigma} q \xrightarrow{v} f
$$
By construction, $u \in L(q_0, \{p\})$ and $v \in L(q, F)$ and thus
$u\sigma v$ belongs to the regular language
$$
R(p \xrightarrow{\sigma} q) =  L(q_0, \{p\}) \sigma L(q, F).
$$
I let you now verify that $L'$ is the union of all languages $R(p \xrightarrow{\sigma} q)$, where the union runs over all transitions $p \xrightarrow{\sigma} q$ labelled by $\sigma$.
